# A notation for games

Tags: pdftex, symbols

How do I type the expression from the snippet right before ", the" ?

There is a tilda (~) below S.

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}



\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{fontspec}

%\usepackage{xypic}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{mypackage}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\pullbackcorner}[1][dl]{\save*!/#1-1pc/#1:(1,-1)@^{|-}\restore}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\newfontfamily\ngg{NewGardiner}
% \usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{babyloniannum}
%\setfont{NewGardiner}
\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]

%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}}
%\newcommand{\stheenumm}{\babyloniannum{1}}

%\newcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\babyloniannum{enumi}}
\MakeRobust\babyloniannum
\MakeRobust\hgnum
\usepackage{enumitem}


%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--{\ngg\symbol{"\the\value{nw}}}}
%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\ngg\symbol{"\the\value{\stepcounter{nw}}}}




\begin{document}

%\show\babyloniannum

%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\babyloniannum{enumi}}

% \xymatrix{A \ar[r] &B}

%      $$
%  \xymatrix@=3pc{
%    & & D \\
%    B \ar[r]\ar@/^/[rru]^{h} & P \ar[ru] \pullbackcorner & \\
%    A \ar [u]^f \ar[r]_g & C \ar[u]\ar@/_/[ruu]_{k} &
%  }
%  $$


\underline{motto:}{ každý den $\pm$ nový princip }\hfill{$\square$}
\bigskip
\bigskip
 \begin{enumerate}[ label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}--\hgnum{\theenumi}]
  \item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
  \item *vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice)
  \item svoboda a volnost
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{document}
```

> ---

**THIS GIVES ANOTHER ERROR**

```
Command Line:   D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "tild4.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(tild4.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/accents\accents.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikz-cd.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-xetex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
 (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.
code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.te
x)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithme
tics.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code
.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.
tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.co
de.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.
tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
 (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
rarytopaths.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
rarymatrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
raryquotes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryarrows.meta.code
.tex))) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\switch.def)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/babel-czech\czech.ldf
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\babel.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\xebabel.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def))))) (mypackage.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/xelatex/babyloniannum\babyloniannum.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/xelatex/xunicode\xunicode.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tipa\t3enc.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/numname\numname.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty) (tild4.aux)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tipa\t3cmr.fd)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

! LaTeX Error: Command `\acute' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.43 \begin{document}
                     
? 

! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.43 \begin{document}
                     


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I don’t recognize the leftmost symbol, I’m afraid. What’s it called, and what does it represent?

Comment: You can get a tilde below with the `stackrel` package.

Comment: By the way, what have you tried so far? That’d help us figure out what you want the basic set-up to be.

Comment: @Davislor Please see my comment below Bernard's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have it with `graphicx` and the `accents` package. Choose which you prefer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

 $\reflectbox{\textsf{G}}_{\!\undertilde{S}}^{\mkern-1mu\delta}(p, P)
 \neq
 \reflectbox{\textsf{G}}_{\!\underaccent{\tilde}{S}}^{\mkern-1mu\delta}(p, P) \quad \reflectbox{\textsf{G}}_{\!\undertilde{S}}^{\mkern-1mu\delta}(p, P)
 \neq
 \reflectbox{\textsf{G}}_{\!\underaccent{\tilde}{S}}^{\mkern-1mu\delta}(p, P) $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bernard Please see my new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552941/a-non-working-almost-mwe-second-definition-of-acute).  I know now: you were missing `mypackage.sty`

Comment: Bernard and @user2925716: thanks, I removed the comments, a normal cleaning process if it's very many of them (and the discussion ended).

Answer (score 4):

Just I add only the symbol `\Game` from the Table 204: ℳ Letter-like Symbols of the Comprensive list symbols:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\Game^a_b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]