# A non-working almost MWE: second definition of `\acute`

Tags: xetex, errors, pdftex, compiling, compilation-error

I have created an almost minimal non-working MWE. There is another package named
`mypackage.sty` which is to be placed at the same directory. This second one is definitely not
Minimal. Can someone make these two work: make them to compile successfully ?

In the third part I'm attaching the error.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{fontspec}



\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{mypackage}

\newcommand{\pullbackcorner}[1][dl]{\save*!/#1-1pc/#1:(1,-1)@^{|-}\restore}

\usepackage{babyloniannum}

\newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}[Ligatures=TeX]


\MakeRobust\babyloniannum
\MakeRobust\hgnum
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\underline{motto:}{ každý den $\pm$ nový princip }\hfill{$\square$}
\bigskip
\bigskip
 \begin{enumerate}[ label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}--\hgnum{\theenumi}]
  \item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
  \item *vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice)
  \item svoboda a volnost

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**mypackage.sty: to be placed at the same directory**

```
% this is my first package
%
% (c) Buffalo Bill
%
%% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%% of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN archives
%% in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt.
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
  [2011/01/11 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hg{Segoe UI Historic}

\def\hgunits#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0133fa\or
^^^^^^0133fb\or
^^^^^^0133fc\or
^^^^^^0133fd\or
^^^^^^0133fe\or
^^^^^^0133ff\or
^^^^^^013400\or
^^^^^^013401\or
^^^^^^013402\else
?\fi}

\def\hgtens#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013386\or
^^^^^^013387\or
^^^^^^013388\or
^^^^^^013389\or
^^^^^^01338a\or
^^^^^^01338b\or
^^^^^^01338c\or
^^^^^^01338d\or
^^^^^^01338e\else
?\fi}

\def\hghundreds#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013362\or
^^^^^^013363\or
^^^^^^013364\or
^^^^^^013365\or
^^^^^^013366\or
^^^^^^013367\or
^^^^^^013368\or
^^^^^^013369\or
^^^^^^01336a\else
?\fi}

\def\hgthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0131bc\or
^^^^^^0131bd\or
^^^^^^0131be\or
^^^^^^0131bf\or
^^^^^^0131c0\or
^^^^^^0131c1\or
^^^^^^0131c2\or
^^^^^^0131c3\or
^^^^^^0131c4\else
?\fi}

\def\hgtenthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0130ad\or
^^^^^^0130ae\or
^^^^^^0130af\or
^^^^^^0130b0\or
^^^^^^0130b1\or
^^^^^^0130b2\or
^^^^^^0130b3\or
^^^^^^0130b4\or
^^^^^^0130b5\else
?\fi}

\def\hghundredthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\else
?\fi}


\DeclareRobustCommand\hgnum[1]{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr20000000+#1\relax}}

%\def\hgnum#1{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr10000000+#1\relax}}
\def\hgnumx#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
\hghundredthousands{#3}%
\hgtenthousands{#4}%
\hgthousands{#5}%
\hghundreds{#6}%
\hgtens{#7}%
\hgunits{#8}%
}


%\RequirePackage{whateverwe need}
\def\hi{Hello, this is my own package}
\let\myDate\date
\newcommand\GoodBye[1][\bfseries]{{#1Good Bye}}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `mypackage.sty'.
```

---

```
Command Line:   D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "tild5.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(tild5.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/accents\accents.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikz-cd.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-xetex.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
 (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.
code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.te
x)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithme
tics.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code
.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.
tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.co
de.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)
) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex)

(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.
tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
 (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.cod
e.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
rarytopaths.code.tex)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tikz-cd\tikzlibrarycd.code.tex
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
rarymatrix.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlib
raryquotes.code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryarrows.meta.code
.tex))) (D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\switch.def)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/babel-czech\czech.ldf
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\babel.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\xebabel.def
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def))))) (mypackage.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/xelatex/babyloniannum\babyloniannum.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/xelatex/xunicode\xunicode.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tipa\t3enc.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/numname\numname.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty) (tild5.aux)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/tipa\t3cmr.fd)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

! LaTeX Error: Command `\acute' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 \begin{document}
                     
? 

! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 \begin{document}
                     


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I can't compile: the compiler is stuck at loading `mypackage.sty`. Furthermore, I don't have Segoe UI Historic (my system is Windows 7).

Comment: @Bernard OK. Have you placed the second window in my OQ into mypackage.sty at the same directory and named it as mypackage.sty ? And furthermore can you comment out Segoe UI Historic and everything connected to it in the first package ?

Comment: Yes I have the .sty file in the same directory, and I  deleted the word  `Historic` (I have the standard Segoe UI).

Comment: we can not run your example as it includes `\usepackage{babyloniannum}` which doesn't seem available, presumably it (re) defines `\acute`.  You are specifying fontspec three times, once in your main document and twice?? in `mypackage.sty` although that is not the cause of the error. (actually I see babyloniannum is on ctan, not in texlive) do you need that package to show the problem?

Comment: @Bernard I think I do not need it to show the problem, but I use it as numbering the list's items which is essential to me. ALso I run XeTeX to compile the two packages.

Comment: It's interesting that the problem happens at `\begin{document}` which leads me to think that it's perhaps somehow connected with the use of `everyshi` by `tikz-cd`? I really should install LaTeX on my computer to be able to try running some of this stuff.

Comment: @DonaldHosek That would be great if you could repair my code.

Comment: @Bernard Bernard GREAT it works now! Please see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26294/fontspec-package-accents-bezos-latex-error-command-acute-already) question's answer: ....................................................................................It works with the no-math option for fontspec, which suppresses fontspec maths adjustments. This is also the behavior if a maths font package such as mathpazo or unicode-math is loaded, so the error would not occur then.

\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{accents}
$\accentset{>}{A}$

Comment: That's really tricky!

Comment: @Bernard Does it work for you too? First, I've found the author's homepage and then searched for him and the error in Google.

Comment: Unfortunately, xelatex is still stuck at loading `mypackage.sty`.

Comment: @Bernard With what error ? Do you have all fonts ?

Comment: No special error: some sort of infinite loop.  I replaced Segoe UI Historic with Segoe UI, since I don't have the former, but no error message about a font problem.

Comment: @Bernard If you drop your email here I'll send you the two files which have compiled correctly for me in the attachment.